# Logic to Have only one Li in my navbar be bolded when clicked: React + Typescript

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, events

In my navbar, I'm currently trying to have only an active or clicked LI be bolded when it is clicked. Currently, I can get it to be bolded, but when I click other LI's, they also get bolded, but the original doesn't revert back to it's normal state. I'm not sure how to incorporate logic where if it's not clicked, then leave it as is. Any ideas to check for the "false" condition or is there a better way I can approach this?

Here is my Navlist component (which is my list of Li's)

```
export class Navitem extends React.Component<INavitem, IState> {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            bolded: false
        };
      }

    makeBold = () => {
        this.setState({
            bolded: true
          })
    };

    render() {
      return (     
        <Link to={this.props.tolink} >
            <li className={this.state.bolded ? "bolded" : ""}onClick={this.makeBold}>{this.props.name}</li>
        </Link>

        );
    }
  }
```

And here is my navbar:

```
const Navbar: React.FC<{}> = props => {
    return (
    <nav> 
      <div id='nav-name'>
        <h1>Matthew Fang</h1>
      </div>
      <div id='nav-space'>
        <Navitem name="Home" tolink="/" ></Navitem>
        <Navitem name="About Me" tolink="/about" ></Navitem>
        <Navitem name="Projects" tolink="/projects" ></Navitem>
        <Navitem name="Contact Me" tolink="/contact" ></Navitem>

      </div>

    </nav>

    );
}
```

And this is just my style that bolds the clicked li

```
.bolded
{
font-weight: bolder;
}
```

Comment: You'd probably want to lift up the state to `Navbar` and pass down `isBold` to the nav items from there. Or better yet, if you're using react-router, use [`NavLink`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md) which lets you style the current route.

Answer (score 0):

React already handle the case of active link. It add an `active` class on the link that is active so you just need to add css for this class.

I see that you use `Link`, but this active class is available for `NavLink`. You can test it on [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-starter) by changing Link by Navink and inspect the code :)